# Why is my Toggle field not showing in Gutenberg?

Tags: theme-development, post-meta, block-editor, react

I am adding a `PluginSidebar` to Gutenberg and it works until I try to add a meta field to the sidebar. Then it doesn't work. I'm not sure why though.

```
import { registerPlugin } from "@wordpress/plugins";
import { PluginSidebar, PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem } from "@wordpress/edit-post";
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";

import { PanelBody, ToggleControl } from '@wordpress/components';

registerPlugin( 'page-layout-plugin', {
    icon: 'smiley',
    render: ( props ) => {
        return (
            <PluginSidebar 
            name="meta-page-settings" 
            title="Gutenberg Settings Sidebar"
            >
                <ToggleControl
                label={__('Show Sidebar?', 'starter')}
                checked={props.attributes.showSidebarAttribute}
                onChange={(val) => props.setAttributes({showSidebarAttribute: val})}
                />
            </PluginSidebar>
        )
    }
} );
```

This is the code before compiling it. The error I am getting it below. I read that we can create the attribute name to be saved so I'm not sure why it isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the attributes:

```
registerPlugin( 'page-layout-plugin', {
    icon: 'smiley',
    attributes: {
      'showSidebarAttribute': {'type': 'boolean', 'default': true}, // <-- and maybe others
    },
    render: ( props ) => {
```

You can drop the quotes of the properties, of course (they are optional), I keep them because the equivalent statement is copied over from the PHP part where the quotes are necessary:

```
 'showSidebarAttribute' => ['type' => 'boolean', 'default' => true],
```

Comment: I am still getting the undefined error sadly

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are conflating `registerPlugin` with `registerBlockType`. The `render` property in `registerPlugin` doesn't receive [any props](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-plugins/#registerplugin) so both `props.attributes` and `props.setAttributes` are not defined here.

Where do you want this data to be saved?

Comment: I wanted it saved as meta data